# How to get the n-th author in a .bib file entry?

Tags: biblatex

Consider the following .bib file:

```
@MISC{test,
  author = {Last1, First1 and Last2, First2 and Last3, First3},
}
```

What do I want?
I want to get the n-th author in a .bib file entry.

First Author: First1 Last1 
Second Author: First2 Last2 
Third Author: First3 Last3

I tried the code below, using `\DeclareCiteCommand` and `\printnames` but I didn't get the desired result. Indeed, the code in the MWE gives me:

First Author: First1 Last1 et al. 
Second Author: First2 Last2, et al. 
Third Author: First3 Last3

But I don't want the comma and the "et al.". I only want the authors.

Notice that I defined the commands `\citeauthorone`, `\citeauthortwo` and `\citeauthorthree`. This is not an elegant tentative. I would rather using something like `\citenthauthor[n]{test}` and get the n-th author. Unfortunately I don't know how to combine a new command that would interact with `\DeclareCiteCommand` passing options.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@MISC{test,
  author = {Last1, First1 and Last2, First2 and Last3, First3},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorone}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printnames[][1-1]{author}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
  
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthortwo}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printnames[][2-2]{author}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
  
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorthree}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printnames[][3-3]{author}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
  


\begin{document}

\noindent
First Author: \citeauthorone{test} \\
Second Author: \citeauthortwo{test} \\
Third Author: \citeauthorthree{test} \\

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a new name format without the code for `andothers`.

Usually I would not recommend this, but if you can give up the usual `postnote` argument you can use its optional argument for the author number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{given-family:noetal}{%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorone}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printnames[given-family:noetal][1-1]{author}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthortwo}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printnames[given-family:noetal][2-2]{author}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorthree}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printnames[given-family:noetal][3-3]{author}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorgeneral}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printnames[given-family:noetal][\thefield{postnote}-\thefield{postnote}]{author}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {}
  
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{test,
  author = {Last1, First1 and Last2, First2 and Last3, First3},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
First Author: \citeauthorone{test}

Second Author: \citeauthortwo{test}

Third Author: \citeauthorthree{test}

First Author: \citeauthorgeneral[1]{test}

Second Author: \citeauthorgeneral[2]{test}

Third Author: \citeauthorgeneral[3]{test}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: First Author: First1 Last1//Second Author: First2 Last2//Third Author: First3 Last3//First Author: First1 Last1//Second Author: First2 Last2//Third Author: First3 Last3]