# How to extract single author (by number) from citation?

Tags: biblatex

[`biblatex`](//ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)'s `\citeauthor{<cite>}` pulls the author (last) names from the citation `<cite>`, shortening it if needed. I'd like to selectively pull author's last names from the citation.

How can I extract a single author, by number, from a citation using the following format (say):

```
\authorname{1}% For the first author
\authorname{2}% For the second author
%...
```

Use cases would include:

- Author FirstAuthor did some research. Then published something with SecondAuthor. One could write "`... together with \authorname{2}~\cite{<cite>}, ...`"
- Sometimes a theorem is named based on authors, like the FirstAuthor-SecondAuthor Theorem. I'd like to pull these using `\authorname{1}-\authorname{2}~Theorem`.

Here is a minimal example that could be used as a base to construct `\authorname`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{ref,
  author  = {A. FirstAuthor and B. SecondAuthor and C. ThirdAuthor},
  title   = {Some title},
  journal = {An amazing journal},
  year    = {2999},
  pages   = {1-100}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{ref}

% \authorname{1}% FirstAuthor
% \authorname{2}% SecondAuthor
% \authorname{3}% ThirdAuthor

\end{document}
```

I've looked into how `\blx@citei@citeauthor` loops through authors, but have been unable to define `\authorname{<num>}`.

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/592397/35864

Comment: Did the linked answer work for you or do you need anything else?

Comment: @moewe: The linked answer helps, but requires a slightly different `\DeclareNameFormat` since I'm only interested in the `family` name, correct? Because of this difference, adding an answer here would be good, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in [How to get the n-th author in a .bib file entry?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/592397/35864) it is possible to abuse the `postnote` argument of a `\...cite...` command defined with `\DeclareCiteCommand` to specify the desired name.

The key is a name format that never issues an "et al." and a `\printnames` call that takes as its optional `<start>-<stop>` argument the `postnote` contents.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{family:noetal}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorgeneral}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printnames[family:noetal][\thefield{postnote}-\thefield{postnote}]{author}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref,
  author  = {A. FirstAuthor and B. SecondAuthor and C. ThirdAuthor},
  title   = {Some title},
  journal = {An amazing journal},
  year    = {2999},
  pages   = {1-100}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\citeauthor{ref}

\citeauthorgeneral[1]{ref}

\citeauthorgeneral[2]{ref}

\citeauthorgeneral[3]{ref}
\end{document}
```

[image: FirstAuthor, SecondAuthor, and ThirdAuthor FirstAuthor SecondAuthor ThirdAuthor]